# Zoo Visitor + Radio button & Matrix fields + Inline error handling

Tags: matrix, zoo-visitor, validation

These don't seem to be playing very nicely together.

Here's what's happening:

I've got a Zoo Visitor registration form that contains generic member fields and well as a couple of required custom fields, of which, some are matrix and one is a radio button.

With inline error handling enabled, I'm seeing intermittent undefined index errors on submit within:

- matrix/ft.matrix.php :: line 1982 :: field_required
- radio/ft.radio.php :: line 131 :: field_pre_populate
- radio/ft.radio.php :: line 150 :: field_pre_field_id
- radio/ft.radio.php :: line 151 :: field_pre_channel_id

Field layout is as follows:

The matrix field is birthdate - 3 selects, all required. I know, I know... use a date field. Client req. But anyway... it should work. And it does sometimes. It has been addressed (sort of) by P&T and only errors out when the radio button following it is set to required.

The radio is gender, but it's not using the member field. And it's required.

At first, this seems obvious - the fields are set to pre-populate from another channel. But they're not. They're all set to 'n' and stored as such in the db and in the settings array. However, when validation runs and loops through settings, it's reading 'n' as NULL. So it errors out when it tries to query 'field_id_' on a null channel.

I'm at a loss here. And open to just about any ideas aside from defaulting everyone to M or F - which actually works when required.

Also - apologies if this is a repeat. I see a bunch of Q&A on related topics but nothing that quite matches my scenario.

Comment: Make sure you’re on the latest version of EE and each of the add-ons. Line 1982 in the latest Matrix doesn’t have anything to do with “field_required”.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. The only reason those line numbers are off is from an earlier fix attempt from a couple of months ago that I tried to carry over. comments are pushing them around. https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/errors_validating_matrix_fields_inline_with_safecracker

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and take credit for a simple mistake that monopolized more time than I'll ever admit. Turns out in my zoo form I had "new_row_0" in one of my hidden fields where it should have been "row_new_0".

Comment: @dandelauro Is issues resolved then? If so, please post your solution as an answer below and select your answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From OP in comments above:

> Just wanted to follow up and take credit for a simple mistake that monopolized more time than I'll ever admit. Turns out in my zoo form I had "new_row_0" in one of my hidden fields where it should have been "row_new_0".